# new dataframe depending on multiple conditions of previous rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column a and b as follows:

```
                 a       b
date                      
2017-06-05  1.1285  1.1110
2017-06-06  1.1285  1.1165
2017-06-07  1.1285  1.1202
2017-06-08  1.1285  1.1195
2017-06-09  1.1285  1.1166
2017-06-12  1.1285  1.1166
2017-06-13  1.1285  1.1166
**2017-06-14  1.1296  1.1166**
2017-06-15  1.1296  1.1167
2017-06-16  1.1296  1.1170
**2017-06-19  1.1296  1.1132**
2017-06-20  1.1296  1.1119
2017-06-21  1.1296  1.1119
2017-06-22  1.1296  1.1119
2017-06-23  1.1296  1.1119
2017-06-26  1.1296  1.1119
2017-06-27  1.1349  1.1128
2017-06-28  1.1391  1.1139
2017-06-29  1.1445  1.1145
2017-06-30  1.1445  1.1172
```

I want to produce a new column c returning value of 1 for rows based on the following conditions:

```
condition 1: df['a'] > df['a'].shift(1) #i.e. an increase of value of a; OR
condition 2: df['b'] >= df['b'].shift(1) #i.e. value of b stays the same or increases after condition 1 happens.
```

In the above example, it means that I would like to have column c showing a value of 1 on 2017-06-14 (because value of a increased on that row) and keep showing value of 1 until 2017-06-19 (because value of b decreased on that row, and between 2017-06-14 and 2017-06-16 column c should show value of 1 because value of b did not decrease after value of column a increase on 2017-06-14.

I spent time on np.where() function but seems not easier to implement the above logic because the logic itself also depends on the result of the logic.

Appreciate any answer.

---------------ADD ON--------------------------
In response to john's follow-up question. Let me re-write the example with much cleaner input and the expected answer (please kindly ignore the above dataset):

`date    a.diff b.diff    c

0  2017-06-05    0.0   0.0  0
1  2017-06-06    0.0   1.0  0
2  2017-06-07    0.0   1.0  0
3  2017-06-08    0.0  -1.0  0 
4  2017-06-09    0.0  -1.0  0
5  2017-06-12    0.0   0.0  0
6  2017-06-13    0.0   0.0  0
7  2017-06-14    1.0   0.0  1
8  2017-06-15    0.0   0.0  1
9  2017-06-16    0.0   0.0  1
10 2017-06-19    0.0   0.0  1
11 2017-06-20    0.0  -1.0  0
12 2017-06-21    0.0   0.0  0
13 2017-06-22    0.0   0.0  0
14 2017-06-23    0.0   0.0  0 
15 2017-06-26    0.0   0.0  0
16 2017-06-27    1.0   1.0  1
17 2017-06-28    1.0   1.0  1
18 2017-06-29    1.0   1.0  1
19 2017-06-30    0.0   1.0  1
20 2017-07-31    0.0  -1.0  0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `diff` as well.

```
In [1185]: df['c'] = ((df.a.diff() > 0) | (df.b.diff() >= 0)).astype(int)

In [1186]: df
Out[1186]:
                 a       b  c
date
2017-06-05  1.1285  1.1110  0
2017-06-06  1.1285  1.1165  1
2017-06-07  1.1285  1.1202  1
2017-06-08  1.1285  1.1195  0
2017-06-09  1.1285  1.1166  0
2017-06-12  1.1285  1.1166  1
2017-06-13  1.1285  1.1166  1
2017-06-14  1.1296  1.1166  1
2017-06-15  1.1296  1.1167  1
2017-06-16  1.1296  1.1170  1
2017-06-19  1.1296  1.1132  0
2017-06-20  1.1296  1.1119  0
2017-06-21  1.1296  1.1119  1
2017-06-22  1.1296  1.1119  1
2017-06-23  1.1296  1.1119  1
2017-06-26  1.1296  1.1119  1
2017-06-27  1.1349  1.1128  1
2017-06-28  1.1391  1.1139  1
2017-06-29  1.1445  1.1145  1
2017-06-30  1.1445  1.1172  1
```

Comment: First of all I deeply apologize for not articulating well. column c should show value of 1 if:
Condition A ( df.a.diff() > 0 & df.b.diff() > 0 ) or Condition B (df.b.diff() > 0 following condition B is true,  as long as condition A is still True) is true.
If Condition B is false. then column C can have value of 1 ONLY if Condition A is True.

According to the above logic,

`2017-06-12  1.1285  1.1166  1

2017-06-13  1.1285  1.1166  1`

column c for these 2 rows should be zero because b on 2017-06-08 is decreased (Condition B False). and 2017-06-09 onwards only depends on Condition A.

Comment: I just updated my question with the clean revised dataset and expected output. Appreciate your patience as I am a new user in stackoverflow.